# Convert different date formats to same in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two different types of date formats in the same column(working on DQL (Data Query Language) and using select command)

EX:

```
 1. 2021-08-12
 2. 9/27/2021
```

Looking to convert both into the same format.

I have tried the below but getting an error:
date_format,
date_parse,
cast

Note: date column data type `'str'`

Comment: `MySQL` or `PostgreSQL`? Please dont tag multiple products.

Comment: Please only tag the database product you actually use!

Answer (score 0):

```
with a as (  
    select '2021-08-12' as str union all
    select '9/27/2021' 
  
)
select STR_TO_DATE(str, case 
                            when LOCATE('-', str) > 0 
                              then 
                                  '%Y-%m-%d' 
                              else                                   
                                  '%m/%d/%Y'                                        
                        end)

from a
```